# Showing that (on $\mathbb{R}^n$) the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm is weaker than any other norm

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Showing that (on $\mathbb{R}^n$) the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm is weaker than any other norm.

I am doing past papers and the question is this:
"Prove that any norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is weaker than the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm. Use this fact to show that on $\mathbb{R}^n$ any two norms are equivalent"

(You can find all the needed definitions [here](http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Norm), save me typing them out)

I have shown that $\exists C>0\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|x\|\le C\|x\|_\infty$ is true. (using the triangle inequality property of $\|\cdot\|$)

I must now show that $\exists C>0\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|x\|_\infty\le C\|x\|$ - I sense I'll need the reverse triangle inequality (simply because that's all I've got) you can find the proof that given the triangle inequality we have the reverse [here](http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Triangle_inequality#Reverse_Triangle_Inequality).

Not sure how though.

---

**Forward case**

Simply $\|x\|\le\sum^n_{i=1}|a_i|\|e_i\|$
Let $M_e=\max_{1\le i\le n}(\{\|e_i\|\})$ then
$\sum^n_{i=1}|a_i|\|e_i\|\le\sum^n_{i=1}|a_i|M_e$ so
$\|x\|\le M_e\sum^n_{i=1}|a_i|$
Let $M_a=\max_{1\le i\le n}(\{|a_i|\})$ then
$M_e\sum^n_{i=1}|a_i|\le M_e\sum^n_{i=1}M_a=nM_eM_a$

But wait! $M_a=\|x\|_\infty$ so we conclude:

$\|x\|\le nM_e\|x\|_\infty$ the proof follows by choosing $C=nM_e$

Comment: Please don't use the definition of equivalence of norms given in your link. It is lacking teh condition that $c>0$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen edited but even without that the "Note also that if
∥⋅∥1
is both weaker and stronger than
∥⋅∥2
they are equivalent " should make it clear

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen how would you write it, $\exists c,C\in\mathbb{R}\forall x\in V[c,C>0\wedge c\|x\|_1\le \|x\|_2\le C\|x\|_1]$ or how it is written, they both look pretty bad.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof by contradiction:

You have shown that there is some $C>0$ such that $\|x\| \le C \|x\|_\infty$.

Suppose for all $n$ there is some $x_n$ such that $\|x_n\|_\infty > n \|x_n\|$. Without loss of generality we may assume $\|x_n\|_\infty = 1$. Since the unit ball (with $\|\cdot\|_\infty$) is compact, we can find a subsequence
and $x$ such that $\|x_{n_k} - x\|_\infty \to 0$. We have $\|x\|_\infty = 1$  and so $x \neq 0$. Also, we have
$\|x_{n_k}\| < {1 \over n_k}$.

We have $\|x\| \le \|x_{n_k}\| + \|x_{n_k} -x \| \le {1 \over n_k} + C \|x_{n_k} -x \|_\infty$ which implies $x = 0$, a contradiction.

Comment: While this is good - PLEASE do an edit where you answer the question, although sequential compactness is good. I was really hoping for a ... nicer proof, by that I mean using norms and finite sums - because as you know any two norms on ANY finite vec space are equiv.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The above does answer the question. It shows that there exists some $n$ such that $\|x\|_\infty \le n\|x\|$ for all $x$.  Can you elaborate what it is that you wanted?

Comment: Good point, sorry for that I came across not how I meant and rather rudely infact. I was hoping for a proof that could easily be applied to any finite vector space, that'd probably end up using the reverse triangle inequality and without mentioning compactness.

Comment: In a normed space, the unit ball is compact **iff** the space is finite dimensional, so I suspect that compactness is inextricably involved in an equivalence proof. Since we are dealing with the $\sup$ norm (for one of the norms), we really only need to consider sequential compactness of $[-1,1]$.

Comment: I didn't know that (that explains my difficulty) - please do give this some thought though, - I've added my +1